# Initializing: cannot convert from '_Ty*' to List<int, std::allocator<Node<T>>>:Node*

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am new to C++.
I am starting to create a container List using class template, but the VS compiler gives me an error if I instantiate the class template List in main like this:
List l(5);
If I remove this line in main() the code is compiled OK. Or if I define class Node outside class List I don't have this error. And the compiler issues error at this line code:

```
    node_ptr head = (alloc.allocate(s));
```

Please help. Thank you very much!

```
    #include "pch.h"  
    #include <iostream>  
    #include <memory>  
    using namespace std;  
    template<class T> class Node; //forward declaration  
    template< class T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<Node<T>>>  
    class List  
    {  
        using data_ptr = T *;  
        using data_type = T;  
        class Node {  
          public:  
             T value;  
             Node* next;  
             Node() : value(data_type()), next(0) {}  
        };  
        using node = Node;  
        using node_ptr = Node*;  

        public:  
          List() : length(0), head(NULL), alloc(std::allocator<int>()) {}  
          explicit List(size_t s) : length(s), head(NULL), alloc(std::allocator<Node>())  
          {  
              node_ptr head = (alloc.allocate(s));  
           }  
          ~List() {};  

        //private:
        node_ptr head;
        size_t   length;
        Allocator  alloc;
    };
    int main()  
    {  
        List<int> l(5); //The compile error is gone if this line is removed
        system("pause");  
        return 0;  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time to format the code. I posted the code OK

Comment: What is the error given by the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

First `Node` is defined to be a class template:

```
template<class T> class Node; //forward declaration
```

And Allocator is defaulted according to that:

```
std::allocator<Node<T>>
```

However, later, Node is defined as an inner class of List, not a template.
That's why the compiler complains: Node* != Node*

One solution is to default the allocator to std::allocator, and use rebind to get a Node allocator:

```
using node_allocator = Allocator::template rebind_alloc<Node<T>>;
```

There are other errors/warnings in your code, e.g: the initialization order in the init list of the List ctor is wrong, or you shadow the class member `head` with a local variable `head`.